# CRON isn't working

Tags: php, cron

I have the following php code set to run as a CRON job. It runs once a day and never returns an error so I assume it is running properly. The problem is, the rows aren't being deleted from my database!

I've tested the php and the variables work. I've tested my query and that works too so I'm at a loss...

```
<?php
$isCLI = ( php_sapi_name() == 'cgi-fcgi' );

if (!$isCLI)
    die("cannot run! sapi_name is ".php_sapi_name());
exit;

//Connect to DB
mysql_connect("xxxxxx.com", "xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());

//Get today's date
$todayis = date("Y-m-d");
$todayis = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todayis)) . " -4 hours");
$todayis = date('Y-m-d', $todayis);

//Delete rows in userContests where reminder is less than or equal to today's date
mysql_query("DELETE FROM userContests WHERE reminder <= '$todayis';") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Can someone explain to me why the rows won't delete?

Comment: What does `crontab -l` say about the job ?

Comment: Why not use MySQL's [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html)?

Comment: @ccKep I have no idea what you're referencing. My host doesn't allow me access to any kind of management for cron. I can only tell it what file to use, nothing else.

Comment: @eggyal I have no idea what event scheduler is or how to use it.

Comment: I suggest adding some debug output (write to a file) and see what happens / where cron stops running / if it's even executed.

Comment: @Jonathan: My comment linked to the manual...

Comment: @eggyal I know, but I'm not going to learn it in 1 day!

Comment: @Jonathan:  Really?  Wow.  `CREATE EVENT foo ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURDATE() DO DELETE FROM userContests WHERE reminder <= CURDATE()`.  I'd be surprised if that took 5 minutes to learn from the manual.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that die/exit combo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the whole script, I would say you have forgotten to connect to the database.

**Edit:** This seems to be the problem:

```
if (!$isCLI)
    die("cannot run! sapi_name is ".php_sapi_name());
exit;
```

That translates to:

```
if (!$isCLI) 
{
    die("cannot run! sapi_name is ".php_sapi_name());
}

exit;
```

So basically you always stop your script on the 6th line, nothing after that will ever be executed.

Comment: I have not. Clearly I won't be pasting that sort of information here.

Comment: @Jonathan It would be helpful to post the whole script to help us troubleshoot, with usernames and passwords as something like `xxx`. Anyway, take a look at my edit.

Comment: I have posted the whole script. That being said, when it dies, it outputs the phrase "cannot run". The fact is, such an output is not delivered ergo it doesn't die which means the script is executing. Let me know what you find!

Comment: @Jonathan `die` and `exit` are the same so just remove the `exit` statement as now you have 2 `die` statements, one in the `if` condition and one after it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a CRON job, it should be using `PHP-CLI` not `PHP-CGI`. You can add this to the top of the file to do the right check.

```
<?php if(PHP_SAPI != 'cli') throw new Exception('Not in CLI mode!');

...
```

Comment: @Jonathan, any CLI task (including CRON) should be using PHP-CLI. Test by calling the script directly from the command line with `$ php scriptname.php`

Comment: I have no command line interface. I can merely choose a file to use with cron. I have no options, no command lines, no settings.

Comment: @Jonathan, ah, then you must be using some kind of administration panel that acts as a *virtual CRON*. Explains all the problems you are having.